# updating template view with error message in django

Tags: django

I have a Django model and form which are defined as follows:

```
class LabelModel(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/label',
                             db_column='path', default='Some Value')
```

The corresponding form is as follows:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    labelled_image = forms.FileField(label='Select the Label image')
```

I have a simple validation method which checks the file extension.

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    import os
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    ext = os.path.split(value.name)[1]  # [0] returns path+filename

    valid_extensions = ['.img']
    if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:           
        return False 

return True
```

Now, in the POST method, I do the following:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        labelled_file = request.FILES['labelled_image']
        has_errors = validate_file_extension(labelled_file)
```

Now, if I have errors, I would like to update the render the page with an error message:

So, my template rendering code looks like:

```
<form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

        <p>{{ form.labelled_image.label_tag }} {{ form.labelled_image }} {{ form.labelled_image.errors }} </p>           

        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
    </form>
```

Now, I do not know how I can update this `{{ form.labelled_image.errors }}` with my own error message so that it can be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's generally the way to fill the `errors` value:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    labelled_image = forms.FileField(label='Select the Label image')

    def clean_labelled_image(self):
        # ... (your validation code here) ...
        raise forms.ValidationError('Custom error message here')
```

By putting the validation in the `clean_<name>` function, you can raise a `ValidationError` that will be placed in `{{form.labelled_image.errors}}` once `form.is_valid()` is run.